# Swiper angular 7 not working when change the class name

Tags: angular, slider, carousel, angular7, swiper.js

I am following this slider: [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/)

I have 2 swiper sliders in my project and both have different classifications.

One slider is working fine with class name `swiper-container`. But when I'm going to change the 2nd slider's class name as below, it is not working.

First slider have 4 items per slide and I want 2nd slider should have 1 item per slide. That's why I want to change the name of slider container.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="intro-swiper-container"> <--- changing this class name
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div *ngFor="let temp of tempArr" class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title intro-title">Header {{temp}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text intro-body">
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-block css-btn" (click)="inforDialogClose()">Skip</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**ts:**

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.intro-swiper-container', {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 50,
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                    },
                    breakpoints: {
                        1024: {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            spaceBetween: 40,
                        },
                        768: {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            spaceBetween: 30,
                        },
                        640: {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            spaceBetween: 20,
                        },
                        320: {
                            slidesPerView: 1,
                            spaceBetween: 10,
                        }
                    }
                });
```

All required library is already imported in `core.module.ts` file. I am not getting why it is not working when I change the class name.

**core.module.ts:**

```
import { SwiperConfigInterface, SwiperModule } from 'ngx-swiper-wrapper';

const DEFAULT_SWIPER_CONFIG: SwiperConfigInterface = {
    direction: 'horizontal',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    keyboard:true,
    mousewheel:true,
    scrollbar:true,
    navigation:true,
    pagination:true,
    breakpoints:{
      640:{
        slidesPerView:1
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

`swiper-container` class is used by swiper css itself to apply styles etc.Instead of removing class you can use some other class  to init swiper something like

```
 <div class="swiper-container s1" > 
 new Swiper('.s1', {

 <div class="swiper-container s2" > 
 new Swiper('.s2', {
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sr86L79/)

Comment: It has only 1 slider

Comment: can you create a stackbliz of your problem

Comment: I have followed the same but somehow it is not working!

Comment: can you create a fiddle or stackblitz of your problem.May be you'r using swiper-container for one swiper try using two diffrent class instead of swiper container class

Comment: I did that too. but May be i'm using second swiper in pop-up, that's why it is not working. Actually I am using in Angular.

Comment: you have to create some reproducible example otherwise it would be very difficult to solve your problem